# Loop through and get value react

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with dynamic input fields, storing those details in firebase like usr_PilotName-1,usr_PilotName-2 etc. Now I want to display those details but I'm not able to get the required result.

Any help Appreciated

```
   render() {
        const { singleuser, classes } = this.props;
        const SPinputsPilot= [];
        if (singleuser) {

            if (singleuser.sp_Role == "Service Provider") {
                for (let i = 0; i < singleuser.sp_NumberofDronePilots; i++) {
                    SPinputsPilot.push(
                        <div>
                            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
                            <p> {singleuser.usr_PilotName-i} </p>
                            </GridItem>
                            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                            <p> {singleuser.usr_PilotLicesnseNumber-'${i}'} </p>
                            </GridItem>
                        </div>)
                }

            }

            return (
                <div>....</div>
```

Comment: What is `SPinputsPilot`? Can you show the `render` function?

Comment: If SPinputsPilot array will have items after this loop, you can do {SPinputsPilot} inside render.  eg: <div className="wrapper">{SPinputsPilot}</div>

Comment: You are not initializing SPinputsPilot. I think, it should be an empty Array.

Comment: render works fine. {singleuser.usr_PilotLicesnseNumber-'${i}'}  this is not working fine.. how can  i pass 'i' value to that?

Comment: I'm receiving 'NaN'

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, **singleuser** is an object and you want to show pilot details. Using forloops like that to populate an array for rendering component is an anti-pattern to React itself.

```
render(){
  const { singleuser, classes } = this.props;
  const SPinputsEquipment = [];
   return singleuser ? (
      Array.from({ length: singleuser.sp_NumberofDronePilots}).map((pilot, i) => (
       <div>
         <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
         <p> {`${singleuser.usr_PilotName}-${i}`} </p>
         </GridItem>
         <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
           <p> {`${singleuser.usr_PilotLicesnseNumber}-${i}`} </p>
         </GridItem>
       </div>))
   ) : 
   <div> ==== No single User ==== </div>
}
```

Check this [working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-mountain-xolc3)

Comment: usr_PilotLicesnseNumber-1
"34567"
usr_PilotName-1
"testing"   ---  this is my firestore document fields

Comment: i'm getting error to this line  <p> {`${singleuser.usr_PilotLicesnseNumber}-'${i}'} </p>

Comment: getting this error - Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

Comment: There was space in this singleuser.sp_NumberofDronePilots, after singleuser. I have updated. Please try again

Comment: I have added working code link above. Check it out.

Comment: @ansh Please select this as answer, if it's solved your problem.